# Etherscan.io Verification Addresses

Tags: transactions, etherscan, addresses, proof-of-stake, contract-verification

It's taking me a long time to verify addresses on Etherscan.io Can someone give me a solution for verifying contract addresses?

Comment: You can try using tools like hardhat: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomicfoundation-hardhat-verify.